# ReWrite only root URL in IIS - ignore everything else?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis, url-rewriting, windows-server-2008

Curious is anyone knows a way to re-write only the root URL of an app in IIS and ignore everything else?

For example:

www.test.com/ re-directs to web.test.com

www.test.com redirects to web.test.com

www.test.com/intro does not redirect

Answer (score 1):

http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite
iis has a url rewrite plugin.when you install this,you can add a rule use regex
www.test.com[/]{0,1}$ this will match www.test.com or www.test.com/ but not match www.test.com/intro,so you can only redirect the match url